# Concrete5 User attributes

Tags: php, concrete5

I figured out how to du this seperatly

Display the user attribute:

```
<?php
 //Create a User object (of the current User)  
 $u = new User();  
 //Creat a UserInfo object with the user ID  
 $ui = UserInfo::getByID($u->getUserID());  
 //Get the Value of your user Attribute  
 $value = $ui->getAttribute('name');  
 //Print it out  
 echo $value;  
?>
```

Display page owner:

```
<?php 
 $ownerID = $cobj->getCollectionUserID();
 $uia = UserInfo::getByID($ownerID);
 $ownerName = $uia->getUserName();
 echo $ownerName 
?>
```

But i cannot figure out how to put them together so it displays the attribute('name'); of the page owner

Can you guys please help

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$uia->getAttribute('name');`? I do not know Concrete5 but according to your two code examples this should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving a little bit more around with the codes.
i figured out that i just needed to move the

```
$cobj->getCollectionUserID();
```

into

```
$ui = UserInfo::getByID($u->getUserID());
```

So the finished code:

```
<?php                   
 //Creat a UserInfo object with the Owner 
 $ui = UserInfo::getByID($cobj->getCollectionUserID() );  
 //Get the Value of your user Attribute  
 $value = $ui->getAttribute('name');  
 //Print it out  
 echo $value;  
?>
```